# what size foil squares to wrap chocolate truffles?

Tags: chocolate, chocolate-truffles

So much leftover chocolate truffle base that I better package nicely and get out of the house:

Is there some ratio or rule of thumb to spare me from experimenting on the right size and shape of bon bon to fit either a 3, 4 or 6" square foil?
Closest answer I find is from foil ordering site stating 3" is for small, 4" medium size candy etc. Whatever that may mean.

Cube, ball or flat-bottomed egg are all fine by me; typically my portioning is not more than an inch thick.

Sorry if this post is more geometry than cooking but appearances count too

Answer (score 2):

Some basic math, assuming spherical candy and the type of foil that fits snugly w.o. twisting the ends (like thin aluminum foil):

- 3" foil -> covers 0.95" candy w.o. overlap -> aim for scant 3/4" balls
- 4" foil -> covers 1.27" candy w.o. overlap -> aim for 1" balls
- 6" foil -> covers 1.91" candy w.o. overlap -> aim for 1.5" balls

I figured 3.14 for Pi would be precise enough, and the formula is:

> circumference = diameter * Pi

For cubic candy:

> circumference = 4 * side

For other blocks (or close enough, e.g. egg-shaped):

> circumference 1 = 2* (height + lenght) 
>   circumference 2 = 2* (height + width) -> use the bigger value for square foil

Of course, you'll want to have a foil *slightly larger* that the circumference, as you need some overlap - just *add 1/4" - 1/2"*, depending on how precise you wrap.

- If you are using the plasticy type of stiff foil that is to be twisted, add at least 1-2" per twist, up to 3" for a more "flashy" effect.

Comment: Thanks, that puts it in the ball park. Too much overlap looks sloppy so under 1/2" works. Looks like I'll be stocking up on 4" and a few 6" sqs